# My AJAX codes doesn't update the Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sql-update

I'm working on a chat application.

The program supposed to insert the text inputted by user to the database using AJAX. But, it isn't working right now. I think it's a simple mistake (e.g. wrong variable name(s) somewhere in my code). Please help.

I have a table in the database which I called *chattest*. The fields are as follows: 
1. Chat_Id (Primary key, auto increment, INT) 
2. Chat_User_Id (INT)
3. Chat_Text (Text)

I have a file, named *classes.php* which contains:

```
<?php

class chat {
private $Chat_Id, $Chat_User_Id, $Chat_Text;

public function getChatId(){
    return $this->Chat_Id;
}
public function setChatId($Chat_Id){
    $this->Chat_Id = $Chat_Id;
}

public function getChatUserId(){
    return $this->Chat_User_Id;
}
public function setChatUserId($Chat_User_Id){
    $this->Chat_User_Id = $Chat_User_Id;
}

public function getChatText(){
    return $this->Chat_Text;
}
public function setChatText($Chat_Text){
    $this->Chat_Text = $Chat_Text;
}


public function InsertChatMessage(){
    include "conn.php";

    $req=$bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO chattest (Chat_User_Id,Chat_Text) VALUES (:Chat_User_Id,:Chat_Text)");
    $req->execute(array(
        'Chat_User_Id'=>$this->getChatUserId(),
        'Chat_Text'=>$this->getChatText()
        ));

}

}

?>
```

and *insert_message.php* file or function, which contains:

```
<?php
session_start();

include "classes.php";
if(isset($_POST['ChatText'])) {
    $chat = new chat();
    $chat -> setChatUserId($_SESSION['id']);
    $chat -> setChatText($_POST['ChatText']);
    $chat -> InsertChatMessage();

}

?>
```

and the chat page containing the AJAX is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<title>Chat Application Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ChatText").keyup(function(e) {
            //When We Press Enter Do
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                var ChatText = $("#ChatText").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'insert_message.php',
                    data:{Chat_Text:"Test Chat"},
                    success:function(){

                        $("#ChatText").val("");
                    }


                });
            }

        });   

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['fname']  ?> </h2>
</br></br>

<div id="ChatBig">
    <div id ="ChatMessages">
    </div>
    <textarea id="ChatText" name="ChatText"> </textarea>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally, below is the script to connect to the db, named *conn.php*:

```
<?php

try{
$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtestt","root","")
}catch(Exception $e){
die("ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Are you checking for *potential* errors? Doesn't look like it. Add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. If that doesn't signal anything, then it's on to the next step of debugging; check everything; typos, console etc.

Comment: Always get the backend part working normally and check it before trying ajax so you know if the problem is frontend or backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the little tiny bug.

at conn.php, it's missing **;**

conn.php supposed to be

```
<?php

try{
$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtestt","root","");
}catch(Exception $e){
die("ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Thank you all for the responses.